# How to use ui:repeat in datatable to append columns?

Tags: jsf

I want to generate a list of tables. 1 table for each month. With 1 column for each day of the month. Here is the JSF piece I am using.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{worklogService.months}" var="monthnum">
    <p:dataTable value="#{worklogService.getTableForMonth(monthnum)}" var="tabrow">
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:outputLabel value="#{tabrow.get(0)}"></h:outputLabel>
        </p:column>
        <ui:repeat value="#{worklogService.getDaysOfMonth(monthnum)}" var="daynum">
            <p:column headerText="#{daynum}">
                <h:outputText value="#{tabrow.get(daynum)}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column> 
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

`#{worklogService.months}` returns `List<Integer>`. One number per Month.
`#{worklogService.getTableForMonth(monthnum)}` returns `List<List<String>>`.

The first column for each table is the same. I want to generate all other columns depending on the month. The result is 12 Tables with only 1 column (the first). What could be the problem here? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This construct fails because `UIData` components like `<p:dataTable>` only support `UIColumn` children which can in case of `<p:dataTable>` only be either `<p:column>` or `<p:columns>`.

In your particular case, you've 2 options:

1. Use `<p:columns>` instead of `<ui:repeat><p:column>`:

   ```
   <p:columns value="#{worklogService.getDaysOfMonth(monthnum)}" var="daynum" headerText="#{daynum}">
       #{tabrow.get(daynum)}
   </p:columns>
   ```
2. Use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<ui:repeat>` ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)):

   ```
   <c:forEach items="#{worklogService.getDaysOfMonth(monthnum)}" var="daynum">
       <p:column headerText="#{daynum}">
           <h:outputText value="#{tabrow.get(daynum)}"></h:outputText>
       </p:column> 
   </c:forEach>
   ```

Comment: Solution 1 won't work due to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6276) in PrimeFaces >4.0(.x) that they 'refuse' to fix (or at least closed for a wrong reason). It happens in other 'repeating'  components to like tab and their own datatable.

Comment: @balus c when in use the datatable inside the ui:repeat scroll bar inside the datatable not working properly (if i scroll my first datatable horizontal scroll bar ,alone with my datatable the second datatable header is also getting scrolled )